# Expression with "starring"

Tags: grammar, idioms

I'd like to compose a phrase with a movie title, a lead actor and 'starring'.

For example the title is "Top Gun", a lead actor Tom Cruise.
In this case, which is/are correct and the most popular?

> Tom Cruise starring "Top Gun"
>
> "Top Gun" starring Tom Cruise
>
> "Top Gun" Tom Cruise starring
>
> .... anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The order is this: title of film - starring - name of star. Of your three examples, only this is correct:

> "Top Gun" starring Tom Cruise

When we us words like 'starring', 'including', 'featuring', 'having', etc, to link two nouns, they go in between the nouns: a film starring Peter Smith, a meal including vegetables, a vacation featuring boat trips, a story having two parts.